# Multi-label classification or multi class classification or sequence labelling problem?

Tags: python, neural-network, label, conv-neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I have some images which look like this one:

[image: example]

They exist of 4 possible characters (A-D) and a length of 4.

Now, I would like to run a neural network, which recognizes each character in the picture. Is this a multi-label (I think so) or a multi-class image recognition problem or something different? And how should I then handle the labels?

To solve the problem, I one hot encoded the label as follows:

```
encoded = my_onehot_encoded('ABAC')

print(encoded)
[[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Is this correct? My objective is obviously not only that the neural network recognizes two As, one B and one C but also on the correct position.

Edit: Is this problem maybe a sequence labelling problem?